# problem with php + mysql ( field name "group" )

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
public function insert($table, $data = array()) {
    $fieldnames = array_keys ( $data );
    var_dump(implode ( ' ,', $fieldnames ));
    $name = '( ' . implode ( ' ,', $fieldnames ) . ' )';
    $value = '(:' . implode ( ', :', $fieldnames ) . ' )';
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table";
    $query .= $name . ' VALUES ' . $value;
    var_dump($query);
    $insert = $this->start->prepare ( $query );
    return $insert->execute ( $data );
}
```

**Question: ok i have a function that helps me simplify the insert statement (pdo) the problem is is when i insert a field if "group" name on it**

```
$a['group'] = $_POST['group'];
$a['tag'] = $_POST['tag'];
$a['information'] = $_POST['information'];
$status= $this->insert ( 'groups', $a);
```

it will generate a mysql error like

> PDOStatement::execute()
>   [pdostatement.execute]:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'group ,tag ,information )
>   VALUES ('agroup', 'atag',
>   'ainformation' )'

this is the query

```
INSERT INTO groups( group ,tag ,information ) VALUES (:group, :tag, :information )
```

im guessing that it should be

```
INSERT INTO groups( "group" ,"tag" ,"information" ) VALUES (:group, :tag, :information )
```

im not sure where should we start from.

Thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have:

```
  INSERT INTO groups( "group" ,"tag" ,"information" ) ...
```

You need to have:

```
  INSERT INTO `groups` ( `group` ,`tag` ,`information` ) ...
```

Do this with the following:

```
  $groups = array('group','tag','information');
  $mysql_groups = '`' . implode('`,`', $groups) . '`';
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO `groups` (' . $mysql_groups . ') ...';
```

Comment: Note that in the ANSI SQL specification, double-quoted identifiers are correct.  MySQL can be [switched into ANSI compliance](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html) if needed.

Comment: Didn't know that Charles, Cheers

Answer (score 10):

Quote `group` with backticks.

#### Example

```
`group`
```

`group` is a reserved word in SQL. You may have used...

```
GROUP BY `id` DESC
```

...or similar before.

If using >= PHP 5.3...

```
$fieldnames = array_map(function($field) {
    return "`$field`";
}, $fieldnames);
```

Comment: yes but im not sure how to do it, is there a function that can appends backtics to an array in php? or something else.

Comment: wew. is there a simpler way? it looks overkill, but yeah it does the job! i will lookin on array map. thanks alex.

Comment: @Adam [Matt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093655/problem-with-php-mysql-field-name-group/6093722#6093722) may be a better choice :)

Comment: yeah thanks! but yes performance does matters because its in the core framework, dunno but it seems to be heavier then below. thanks again.